# On heroku chromedriver buildpack doesn't support chrome buildpack

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a web scraper using python.

To deploy it on heroku, I took this article as reference.
https://www.andressevilla.com/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku/

And added these buildpacks.
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

But when I run the code on heroku, this error occurs.

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:
> session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
> version 90 Current browser version is 89.0.4389.114 with binary path
> /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome

It looks like the chromedriver buildpack doesn't support chrome buildpack.

Does any other buildpack work? Or I can try any other way to deal with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Heroku Chrome Driver Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver) allows you to choose version of chrome driver but by default it should have installed latest version of it available. You can set config var(Environment variable) `CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION`=`89.0.4389.23` to download a chromedriver version compatible for chrome 89. After adding the variable, you'd want to redeploy for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Ok, I set config var and push again.
Then it works!
Thanks!!!

Comment: Hello @jenjojo I am stucked in the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77525230/test-is-running-fine-on-heroku-cli-but-on-heroku-ui-test-run-is-failing

Request to please help me