# Test is running fine on Heroku CLI , But on Heroku UI Test Run is failing

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

**Please Help**

Hello My code is running fine on heroku CLI But on heroku UI , Test Run is failing

Ideally heroku CLI & heroku UI must behave same

```
{
  "name": "testingPOC",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --spec ./features/abc-test/test.feature",
    "start": "npm install"
  },
  "author": "Testing",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.11.2",
    "chromedriver": "^119.0.1",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.5.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "puppeteer": "^21.3.8",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Getting error on heroku UI as

```
----> Running Node.js buildpack tests...
> testcheck@1.0.0 test
> npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --spec ./features/abc-test/test.feature
Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-11-21T17:41:20.834Z
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /features/abc-test/test.feature
[0-0] 2023-11-21T17:41:22.646Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: unknown error: no chrome binary at /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
[0-0] 2023-11-21T17:41:22.648Z ERROR webdriver: unknown error: unknown error: no chrome binary at /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - /features/abc-test/test.feature
2023-11-21T17:41:22.778Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: Error in onCompleteHook: Error: 'options.jsonDir' does not exist. Error: json does not exist.
Spec Files:  0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:01 
-----> Node.js buildpack tests failed with exit status 1
```